# How to check if a view controller's view is getting flipped/toggled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I need to somehow check in the code if by clicking a button (doing an action), it is getting the view controller's view toggled

I am using

```
if ([currentViewController.view respondsToSelector:@selector(setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:)])
```

but this one doesn't look like working

Usually this code used to get the view toggled

```
[UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self cache:YES];

[mainView removeFromSuperview];

[self addSubview:infoView];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having the view controller's view manage the flipping. I'm sure that can work, but it's more common to let the view controller manage that sort of thing. If you do that, then the view controller will *know* when the view has been flipped, because it did the flipping.

If you're going to stick with having the view controller's view manage the transition, then you'll have to have the view controller ask its view about the state of the interface. From your view controller, you'd do something like:

```
BOOL flipped = [self.view isInterfaceFlipped];
```